# Newbie Question : Integrating via WSDL import/export

Tags: integration

I am extremely new to Integration as such I need a little help with the following.

I wanted to integrate my two developer instances such that if an Account is created in one instance, an account with the same data will be created in another instance.

I know we can achieve the above via S2S but I really want to send actual record via Integration.

**My colleague mentioned that I can "generate wsdl" from one org and import the generated wsdl in the second org and call out the methods from the first org...Is it really possible ?.**

Would appreciate if someone can tell me the name of this technique and any pointers or pdfs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating WSDL and importing is suitable for large level integration which needs full control over all objects and operations. If you just need to sync Account alone, you can simply create a global class and a method inside that with webservice keyword. Please check link below,

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services_methods_considerations.htm

Comment: I would like to read more about the import & export of wsdl and invoking. Can you tell me of this technique ?

Comment: Please check the link - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts. Also check http://salesforcecodes.blogspot.com/2015/04/integration-between-java-app-and.html for connecting to salesforce from local java client